# Ignore overflow of parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a the following dropdown html structure and css, it's parent has an overflow hidden -

The problem I am having is that when you select the dropdown, it is cut off by the overflow hidden, I need it to ignore the overflow.

I have looked at changing the dropdowns position to fixed, but then I would need to calculate its position for each dropdown, any other suggestions would help!

```css
.overflow-container {
  display: block;
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dropdown-container:hover .dropdown1 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-container">
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Select an option
    <ul class="dropdown1">
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 1</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 2</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Select an option
    <ul class="dropdown1">
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 1</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 2</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Select an option
    <ul class="dropdown1">
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 1</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 2</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

See working JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/DarianSteyn/oq1w6eds/7/

The structure is built using a plugin which sets the html and css. I am able to change the css but not the html structure. I also cant change the height of the parent, it needs to be scrollable if there are multiple dropdowns.

Comment: do you want to increase the height of the outer div, on opening dropdown items?

Comment: Just override the CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant increase the height, that would be an obvious fix yes.

Comment: remove the overlfow?

Comment: i think overflow is correct, remove height from the css for overflow-container, it will work

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it needs to have a fixed height to fit in a certain amount of space. It needs overflow auto to be scrollable if there are multiple dropdowns

Comment: If it would help you then this plugin can solve your problem. 
https://select2.org/

Comment: Are you trying to create navigation menu ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` and use margin or translate to adjust the position. Then  **don't** add `position:relative` to the parent element so it get ignored by the overflow.

```css
.overflow-container {
  display: block;
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dropdown-container:hover .dropdown1 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown1 {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-container">
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Select an option
    <ul class="dropdown1">
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 1</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 2</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Select an option
    <ul class="dropdown1">
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 1</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 2</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-container">
    Select an option
    <ul class="dropdown1">
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 1</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 2</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```